# Make multiple elements visible on drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a code in which three image src with id `drag1`, `drag2`, `drag3` each one can be dragged and dropped to `div1`..

My problem is, on dropping the second and third image it is not visible in #div1

How to make second and third image visible on drop?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="https://picsum.photos/200" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
<img id="drag2" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
<img id="drag3" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?gravity=east" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there's no problem with your actual code, and it's behaving the same way with the 3 `images`.

The problem is that your `div` has only `70px` as `height` so only first image can be visible and the second two elements are inside the `div` but aren't displayed on screen, you can fix that by changing the div `height` or making it stretch with content.

**Demo:**

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

}
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 370px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="https://picsum.photos/200" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
<img id="drag2" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
<img id="drag3" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?gravity=east" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

Comment: @wtp Cool, glad it helps :)